# Do we have a custom "launched ad"?

Tags: discussion, design

I don't know if there's an official term for these, but I'm referring to the dynamically generated Stack Exchange site ads:

[image: screenshot of Pro Webmasters ad]

I don't do a whole lot of browsing outside of our site, but I don't think I've ever seen one for Graphic Design.

The URL pattern doesn't seem all that difficult to crack ([`webmasters.png`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/webmasters.png), [`english.png`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/english.png), [`gaming.png`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/gaming.png), [`math.png`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/math.png), [`ubuntu.png`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/ubuntu.png), [`travel.png`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/travel.png)). I've tried guessing the URL of what ours might be (`graphic.png`, `design.png`, `graphicdesign.png`, `graphic-design.png`, `gd.png`) without any success.

Does our site have a custom ad like this? If not, perhaps this should be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) instead?

Comment: Not sure if creating these is a default part of the site design process or not. Let's find out!